# How create rails model if db table name include numbers?

Tags: sqlite, core-data, ruby-on-rails-4, model, activesupport

I'm developing application, which generate database for iOS mobile application.
But iOS apps use CoreData databases (sqlite with strange association structure).

I understand how can I work with this structure, but if I use sqlite/pg/mysql in case of many-to-many association (table `Category` and table `Product` etc.) I create 3rd table like `Categories_products`.
But unfortunately CoreData doesn't create `Categories_products` table - it creates table `z_2product`, where 2 is ID of `Category` table...

Here is an error:

```
2.1.1 :010 >   CoreData::ZMetadata.all
  CoreData::ZMetadata Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "z_metadata".* FROM "z_metadata"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<CoreData::ZMetadata Z_VERSION: 1, Z_UUID: "069CF377-DE3B-4D00-A3A9-C7CA01E7AD86", Z_PLIST: "bplist00\xD6\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\a\t\n\x17\x18\x19_\x10\x1ENSStoreModelVersionIdentif...">]> 
2.1.1 :011 > CoreData::Z2product.all
NameError: uninitialized constant CoreData::Z2product
    from (irb):11
    from /Users/bmalets/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/bmalets/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/bmalets/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
    from /Users/bmalets/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/bmalets/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/bmalets/Documents/ror_projects/freelance/mobile_market/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/bmalets/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/bmalets/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
2.1.1 :012 >
```

I tried to create a rule for these tables in `config/initializers/inflections.rb`:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect| 
   inflect.irregular 'media',        'medias'
   inflect.irregular 'z_2product',   'z_2product'
   inflect.irregular 'z_3value',     'z_3value'
   inflect.irregular 'z_metadata',   'z_metadata'
   inflect.irregular 'z_primarykey', 'z_primarykey'
end
```

But it doesn't helps me(((

Problem:

So in my Rails app, I create `model Z2product` to work with `z_2product` table in CoreData DB. But rails odes not like numbers in model names :(

P.S. If rails active_record cannot connect sqlite table with name like "z_2product", I will write my own adapter using for example this gem [sqlite3-ruby](https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby)...

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails does not allow number as first character of model name!
But! :)

If you have a number in database table name, you need to just rename your model and set table_name:

```
class CoreData::ZTwoProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "core_data_#{Rails.env}".to_sym
  self.table_name = 'z_2products'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not, most likely cannot, reverse engineer the SQLite database that Core Data uses. Rather, you should be creating an appropriate model, entity subclasses and process the import record for record.

Independent from its database implementation, Core Data does not define join tables as do relational databases; instead it uses a so-called "relationship".

I think the easiest solution is to do an easily readable export, e.g. in JSON, and then import into Core Data on first run.

Comment: I investigated core data structure and connect core_data db as 2nd database. Now I create additional models, but have a problems just with model names like "z_2product"...

Comment: As one way of resolving this problem - I think I can work with "z_category_product" model etc., and before exporting change z_category_product" to "z_2product" using migration. But I think it's not the best way...

Comment: the problem is - how to work with table like "z_2product" in rails project.

Comment: I don't want to write my own core_data adapter - it's too long and hard :'(  :D

Comment: You need a solid iOS expert to help coordinate the data transfer between the two systems. I stand by my answer - don't reverse engineer the database layer of Core Data.

Answer (score 0):

It works using "sqlite3-ruby" gem:

```
2.1.1 :088 >   db = SQLite3::Database.new "db/core_data/productCoreData_development.sqlite"
 => #<SQLite3::Database:0x007ffb01e51f60 @tracefunc=nil, @authorizer=nil, @encoding=nil, @busy_handler=nil, @collations={}, @functions={}, @results_as_hash=nil, @type_translation=nil, @readonly=false> 
2.1.1 :097 >   db.execute( 'SELECT "z_2products".* FROM "z_2products"' ){ |row| p row }
 => #<SQLite3::Statement:0x007ffb01ee2498 @connection=#<SQLite3::Database:0x007ffb01e51f60 @tracefunc=nil, @authorizer=nil, @encoding=#<Encoding:UTF-8>, @busy_handler=nil, @collations={}, @functions={}, @results_as_hash=nil, @type_translation=nil, @readonly=false>, @remainder="", @columns=["Z_2CATEGORIES", "Z_3PRODUCTS"], @types=["INTEGER", "INTEGER"]> 
2.1.1 :098 >
```